# How to set width on dropdown item in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to add a little dropdown to the right side of my navbar.
I'm trying to set a width to a elements by adding a new CSS class which set the width, but nothing I tried works.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#"
      id="navbarDropdown"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
      class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
      some text
      </a>
      <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownLangMenu"
          class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item">AA</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">BB</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Everything works fine, except the width of a elements. Every link has only two characters, but the width of them is very large and it goes beyond the width of the screen:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a min-width on the dropdown menu in bootstrap.
You can reset it like this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu.show {
    min-width: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>      
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item">AA</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item">BB</a>
        </div>
      </li>      
    </ul>   
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```